# How to import multilingual and foreign key entries?

Tags: plugin-feedme

I am using Feedme to create batch import content.
I am in this use case :

- My site is multilingual (so I have sites EN, FR... in a group site)
- My entries have foreign keys to other entries

For my first level entries, I have no issue with translation, it is more about my foreign key objects :

- Try to keep translation in the right site
- Try to keep link to the FK parent entry

It would be great to have some documentation in these situations.

Thanks !